# Cannot sign data without `client_email` even when provided in service account key

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm getting `Caused by SigningError: Cannot sign data without 'client_email'.` when trying to fetch gcloud storage data. I do have a service account json that includes the proper client_email which I provide when getting the storage but I still get this issue.

The service account that `GOOGLE_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEYFILE` leads to has the proper access rights to every storage related services as it has `storage admin` role

Not much I can share but here is the code that gets the storage():

```js
const storage = new Storage({
            projectId: projectId,
            keyFilename: process.env.GOOGLE_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEYFILE, // correct path to service account json file
        });

        console.log(storage);
        const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles({
            prefix,
        });
```

error I get:

```
Caused by SigningError: Cannot sign data without `client_email`.
    at GoogleAuth.sign (/Users/User/app-firebase/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:648:19)
    at sign (/Users/User/app-firebase/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/signer.js:91:35)
From previous event:
    at File.wrapper (/Users/User/app-firebase/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:42:16)
    at _callee$ (webpack-internal:///./src/api/utils/StorageUtils.ts:219:81)
```

**Environment details**

OS: macOS 12.4
Nodeversion: 16.15.0
npm version: 8.5.5
@google-cloud/storage version: 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this, I needed to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and point it to my service account json in my environment file as described here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#attached-sa

Now it works without any issues.

Comment: If you read ADC page, you should understand that you can avoid using service account key file and use your own account. Service account key file is a bad practice!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere you're right BUT you can't _sign_ data without using a service account which is a frustrating omission from the docs, especially because the ADC example uses a Storage instance as its ADC example.

They explicitly refer to use of a SA [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#overview).